# defaultparameter in constructor magically becomes class variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem understanding the following:

```py
    class Test():
        def __init__(self, data = []):
            self.data = data

    a = Test()
    b = Test()
    a.data.append(1)
    print(b.data) # prints [1]

    class Test1():
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data

    a = Test1([])
    b = Test1([])
    a.data.append(1)
    print(b.data) # prints []


    class Test2():
        def __init__(self, data = 1):
            self.data = data

    a = Test2()
    b = Test2()
    a.data = 2
    print(b.data) # prints 1
```

It prints out `[1]`
I was expecting that the instance variable `data` of `b` would be an empty list, because it is a instance variable and not a class variable!
If I do the same thing without a default parameter and just pass an empty list to the parameter `data` it works. It also works with an int as a default parameter. I know lists are passed by reference, but that shouldn't be happening anyways.
How? why? Am I not seeing something here??

Comment: There is an explanation of why that happens here: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well.

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Answer (score 0):

Your default argument for `data` is a mutable type! When python is creating the definition of your `Test` class, it only makes one instance of the default arguments. This means that every time you create a `Test` object, it's `data` property will be pointing to the same list. After you create both of your `Test` objects, both of their `.data` properties point to the exact same list in memory. If you change that list once, it will change it for all your `Test` classes. The `list.append` method modifies the list in place, hence why you see this behavior.

Notice in your `Test1` case, you are creating two different empty lists and assigning them to the `.data` property. Since these are two separate lists, you can change either one however you please without affecting the other.

Python `int`'s are not mutable, and even if they were, you are overwriting the `.data` property in your `Test2` example so you get the expected behavior.

But sometimes, your function needs the default argument to be a `list` or some other mutable type! What you can do is assign the default value to `None`, and then check if the value is `None` inside the function. If it is, assign your property to your actual desired default value. Like this:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data =  [ ] if data is None else data
        # Set self.data to an empty list if data is none, otherwise, set it to whatever data already is.

a = Test()
b = Test()
a.data.append(1)
print(f"a.data:{a.data}, b.data:{b.data}")
# >> a.data:[1], b.data:[]
```